# What is the possible purpose of this lambda usage?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I found a piece of code from a co-worker who no longer works for the same company as me, so I can't ask them myself.

This was the original code (1):

```
Class Foo {
  void bar(InType i, OutType* o);
};

void Foo::bar(InType i, OutType* o) {
  o = something();
  if (!o->valid()) throw Exception();
}
```

They changed it to (2):

```
Class Foo {
  OutType bar(InType i);
};

auto Foo::bar(InType i) -> OutType {
  OutType o;
  o = something();
  if (!o->valid()) throw Exception();
  return o;
}
```

This appears the same as (3):

```
Class Foo {
  OutType bar(InType i);
};

OutType Foo::bar(InType i) {
  OutType o;
  o = something();
  if (!o->valid()) throw Exception();
  return o;
}
```

I understand that #2 is a member variable that is a lambda, but what do this gain? The lambda is still called just like a regular function syntactically.

**Is there a real reason to use #2 instead of #3?**

Comment: A lambda has the form `[](){}`.  You don't have that here.  What you are seeing in #2 is called a trailing return type

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the keyword, now I can do some more reading. That explains why I couldn't find any lambda usage like this.

Comment: No worries.  It's hard to search when you don't even know the search terms.  FWIW, I googled *function with auto and arrow after it c++* to get the dupe target.  That might help your google-fu in the future.